# mapping problem : "go back" button opens a dialog box in 12.10

Tags: keyboard

I just made a fresh install of 12.10 and the "go back" or "previous page" button on my keybord (lenovo thinkpad), opens a dialog box when used with firefox.

How can I avoid this?

Thanks

[image: dialog box]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this command:

```
dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

to reset the keyboard layout and choose another layout. Now it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

xbindkeys will help you. it has a GUI.

http://www.nongnu.org/xbindkeys/xbindkeys.html#download

in command line, use xev and xmodmap

Comment: I can't make xbindkeys work. Can't I relaunch the auto detect keyboard layout from ubuntu installation ?